# how to cretae zip file using zipfile in python?

Tags: python, file, zip

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os.path import basename

src = "C:\git\mytest"

full_path=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        full_path.append(os.path.join(root, name))

with ZipFile('output.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
    for item in full_path:
        zipObj.write(item, basename(item))
```

1. Trying to create a zip file with containing some file of a specific folder.
2. In specific folder has some files. then it will add to zip file
3. In the mentioned code, one zipfile is created but there is no file. I am not getting the exact reason

Comment: @Salwat: Someone already fixed your formatting. Why do you insist on screwing it up again?

Comment: @Sören, my problem is all files from the source are not zipped. its shows no files in the zip

Comment: That wasn't my question at all.